# Rewrite index.php in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I started a blog and when I changed my permalink structure to `/%postname%/` I get a Page Not Found error.  I want my url to look like this:

http://bobbybeckner.com/sharepoint-list-and-linq-using-jquery-and-ihttphandler/

not this:

http://bobbybeckner.com/index.php/sharepoint-list-and-linq-using-jquery-and-ihttphandler/

I read a few posts about changing .htaccess but found no clear solution.  Any code examples welcome or recommendations on wordpress plug-ins would be *greatly* appreciated.

**Update**
I thought it would be important to mention that my host is running IIS7 but does not allow users to touch it.  In addition, I'm uncertain of any restrictions on the .htaccess file or any other configuration limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.htaccess` files only apply to Apache (well, maybe some other servers use it too, but not IIS). AFAIK URL rewriting for IIS is possible, but not as easy.

[ISAPIRewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) appears to be a commercial application that does this, but of course, you'd need to get it installed on your server.

Personally, I wouldn't lose any sleep over having `/index.php/` in your urls.

Comment: Apache?!  Oh, noes!  I'm going to go give my host a hard time :)  No, you're probably right... it might not be worth losing sleep over (:  Thanks for the speedy reply friend-- fancy green check for you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you fill out the structure, if the .htaccess file is writable it will apply the rewrite for you, and if it isn't it will show what the contents should be at the very bottom of the page. Did you check the bottom of the page if it is not writable?

You do NOT have to code this yourself.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for the tip!  Good to know what wordpress is doing behind the magic curtain.  I wrote my own URL rewriting tool long ago before all this buzz started, but I mean c'mon those days are gone...

I checked the page and didn't see anything at the bottom (footer).  Shall I look at the source code?

Nonetheless, thanks again.

Comment: No problem! If you did not see anything, then Wordpress must have detected your server was incapable of managing rewrites, though I do not know why they would have displayed the page at all then. What version of wordpress are you using?